# VBA: Add comments to cells from other cells content if another cell = 1

Tags: excel, vba, comments

I need to add comments to cells using the content of cell.offset(,23) if the cell.offset(,45) = 1

This is what i have attempted:

```
Sub CellToCmt2()

  Dim c As Range
  For Each c In Selection
    If target.Offset(, 45) <> 1 Then Resume Next
    If target.Offset(, 45) = 1 Then
      Application.EnableEvents = False
      On Error Resume Next
      With c.Offset(, 23)
        .NoteText Text:=.Value
      End With
      target.ClearContents
      On Error GoTo 0
    End If
  Next c

End Sub
```

But as I have little VBA knowledge I keep getting errors.

Any help would be much appreciated

**Edit:** This is the code I have that works

```
Sub CellToCmt2()
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Selection
If c.Offset(, 45) = 1 Then
    On Error Resume Next
    With c
        c.NoteText Text:=c.Offset(, 23).Value
    End With
    target.ClearContents
    On Error GoTo 0
End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Run-time error '13'Type mismatch when tried with amended code by Steve S

Comment: What is `target` and where is it declared? Do you know which line of code is causing the error?

Comment: I have changed target to c, but am still getting the error. its on line 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one, this bit does nothing:

```
If target.Offset(, 45) <> 1 Then Resume Next
```

Regardless of whether the conditions are met, you move along to the next step.  May as well take it out altogether.

Also, when I use the macro recorder to input a comment I get the code:

```
c.Comment.Text Text:="test"
```

So maybe try "Comment.Text" instead of "NoteText"

Edit:

You probably want to change

```
With c.Offset(, 23)
  .NoteText Text:=.Value
End With
```

To

```
c.NoteText Text:=c.Offset(, 23).Value
```

Comment: Thanks, that's got rid of the errors but it doesn't add the comments

Comment: To be clear, you're looking for a "1" value 45 columns to the right of some "search index" column, and if found, you are wanting to put comment text into a column 23 columns to the right, correct?  You know that the column "c.Offset(, 23)" is getting the comment from it's own cell value?

Comment: Where are you trying to get the comment from?  From the target cell?

Comment: No from the cell in the same row 23 columns to the right

Comment: So you want the comment in the target column?  If so, see my revision

Answer (score 0):

Should `target` be `c`?  For example:

```
If c.Offset(, 45) <> 1 Then Resume Next
If c.Offset(, 45) = 1 Then
```

Comment: Just tried it but with no luck, I get Run-time error '13'Type mismatch